# Installation of Phonegap on Windows after installing NodeJS

Tags: windows, node.js, cordova, installation

I'm trying to install Phonegap on my computer (Windows) but the instructions on http://phonegap.com/install/ just seem to be incorrect or incomplete. I installed NodeJS as they suggested and ran the following code afterwards:

```
C:\> npm install -g phonegap
```

But this is the result:

```
C:\> npm install -g phonegap
...
```

In other words, there's nothing happening. Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the steps over [here](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/phonegap-3-cli-setup-mac-windows/) for installing on Windows and Mac.
You need to install Git and Ant at the minimum for PhoneGap. I did follow all the steps and it worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap can be installed without using Node js. Just download the Phonegap zip from its official website , unzip it and Set the 'environment variables' pointing to the bin folder within the unzipped folder. Then you can use the 'create' command along with some parameters in cmd for windows or in terminal for mac; for creating a new application. Xcode for ios and Android SDK can be used to edit and test your Phonegap app afterwards . Check out [link](http://cookieflow.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/installing-android-4-2-sdk-and-phonegap-2-4-0-on-windows-7/)

And if using nodejs , check this [link](http://chrisbitting.com/2014/01/06/installing-starting-with-phonegap-on-windows-for-cross-platform-mobile-development/).